# How to iterate through block devices using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have around 10 EBS volumes attached to a single instance. Below is e.g., of `lsblk` for some of them. Here we can't simply mount xvdf or xvdp to some location but actual point is xvdf1, xvdf2, xvdp which are to be mounted. I want to have a script that would allow me to iterate through all the points under xvdf, xvdp etc. using python. I m newbie to python.

```
[root@ip-172-31-1-65 ec2-user]# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvdf    202:80   0   35G  0 disk 
├─xvdf1 202:81   0  350M  0 part 
└─xvdf2 202:82   0 34.7G  0 part
xvdp   202:0    0    8G  0 disk 
└─xvdp1 202:1    0    8G  0 part
```

Comment: What output are you hoping to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
def parse(file_name):
        result = []
        with open(file_name) as input_file:
                for line in input_file:
                        temp_arr = line.split(' ')
                        for item in temp_arr:
                                if '└─' in item or '├─'  in item:
                                        result.append(item.replace('└─','').replace('├─',''))
        return result


def main(argv):
        if len(argv)>1:
                print 'Usage: ./parse.py input_file'
                return
        result = parse(argv[0])
        print result
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The above is what you need. You can modify it to parse the output of lsblk better.
Usage:
1. Save the output of lsblk to a file. 
E.g. run this command: `lsblk > output.txt`
2. `python parse.py output.txt`

Answer (score 9):

If you have a relatively new `lsblk`, you can easily import its json output into a python dictionary, which then open all possibilities for iterations.

```
# lsblk --version
lsblk from util-linux 2.28.2
```

For example, you could run the following command to gather all block devices and their children with their name and mount point. Use `--help` to get a list of all supported columns.

```
# lsblk --json -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT
{
"blockdevices": [
    {"name": "vda", "mountpoint": null,
        "children": [
            {"name": "vda1", "mountpoint": null,
            "children": [
                {"name": "pv-root", "mountpoint": "/"},
                {"name": "pv-var", "mountpoint": "/var"},
                {"name": "pv-swap", "mountpoint": "[SWAP]"},
            ]
            },
        ]
    }
]
}
```

So you just have to pipe that output into a file and use python's json parser. Or run the command straight within your script as the example below shows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.7

import json
import subprocess

process = subprocess.run("/usr/bin/lsblk --json -o NAME,MOUNTPOINT".split(), 
                            capture_output=True, text=True)

# blockdevices is a dictionary with all the info from lsblk.
# Manipulate it as you wish.
blockdevices = json.loads(process.stdout)


print(json.dumps(blockdevices, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I remixed minhhn2910's answer for [my own purposes](https://cloudfleet.io) to work with encrypted partitions, labels and build the output in a tree-like dict object. I'll probably keep a more updated version as I hit edge-cases [on GitHub](https://github.com/cloudfleet/blimp-engineroom/blob/7b73e1462e513e9b89fafdd10f7425bff7e7c52e/bin/cryptpart/check_partitions.py), but here is the basic code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
import re
import pprint

def parse_blk(blk_filename):
    result = []
    with open(blk_filename) as blk_file:
        disks = []
        for line in blk_file:
            if line.startswith('NAME'): # skip first line
                continue
            blk_list = re.split('\s+', line)
            node_type = blk_list[5]
            node_size = blk_list[3]
            if node_type in set(['disk', 'loop']):
                # new disk
                disk = {'name': blk_list[0], 'type': node_type, 'size': node_size}
                if node_type == 'disk':
                    disk['partitions'] = []
                disks.append(disk)
                # get size info if relevant
                continue
            if node_type in set(['part', 'dm']):
                # new partition (or whatever dm is)
                node_name = blk_list[0].split('\x80')[1]
                partition = {'name': node_name, 'type': node_type, 'size': node_size}
                disk['partitions'].append(partition)
                continue
            if len(blk_list) > 8: # if node_type == 'crypt':
                # crypt belonging to a partition
                node_name = blk_list[1].split('\x80')[1]
                partition['crypt'] = node_name


        return disks

def main(argv):
    if len(argv)>1:
        print 'Usage: ./parse.py blk_filename'
        return
    result = parse_blk(argv[0])
    pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4).pprint(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

It works for your output as well:

```
$ python check_partitions.py blkout2.txt
[   {   'name': 'xvdf',
        'partitions': [   {   'name': 'xvdf1', 'size': '350M', 'type': 'part'},
                          {   'name': 'xvdf2', 'size': '34.7G', 'type': 'part'}],
        'size': '35G',
        'type': 'disk'},
    {   'name': 'xvdp',
        'partitions': [{   'name': 'xvdp1', 'size': '8G', 'type': 'part'}],
        'size': '8G',
        'type': 'disk'}]
```

This is how it works on a slightly more complicated scenario with docker loopback devices and encrypted partitions.

```
$ python check_partitions.py blkout.txt
[   {   'name': 'sda',
        'partitions': [   {   'crypt': 'cloudfleet-swap',
                              'name': 'sda1',
                              'size': '2G',
                              'type': 'part'},
                          {   'crypt': 'cloudfleet-storage',
                              'name': 'sda2',
                              'size': '27.7G',
                              'type': 'part'}],
        'size': '29.7G',
        'type': 'disk'},
    {   'name': 'loop0', 'size': '100G', 'type': 'loop'},
    {   'name': 'loop1', 'size': '2G', 'type': 'loop'},
    {   'name': 'mmcblk0',
        'partitions': [{   'name': 'mmcblk0p1',
                              'size': '7.4G',
                              'type': 'part'}],
        'size': '7.4G',
        'type': 'disk'}]
```